# Graphics.DrawLines : Parameter is not valid

Tags: winforms, graphics, delphi-prism, oxygene

For this problem, I did comb through Stackoverflow similar questions for an answer. Although a lot of them were helpful, they didn't solve my problem. My program draws polygon on a winform using graphics.DrawLines method as follows.

```
g.DrawLines(thepen,pts);
```

But that keeps raising, "Parameter is not valid", error. So, I changed that line of code as follows to see if it makes any difference.

```
g.DrawLines(new pen(color.Black),pts);
```

Again, it is raising the same error. pts is an array of system.drawing.point and thepen is a system.drawing.pen.

If I completely comment it out, my program has no issue that it doesn't raise any error. However, what's weird is that the same code used to work just fine for the last 3 or 4 months. Since yesterday, I can't seem to get it working again.

Is there a property setting for the winform that needs to be set?

**UPDATE** Here is the actual draw method

```
method TMakerPoly.Draw;
var
  pts: Array of point;
  i:integer;
  theBrush1:HatchBrush;
  theBrush2:SolidBrush;
begin
  if (theBrushStyle = HatchStyle.Wave) then
     theBrush1 := new HatchBrush(theBrushStyle,Color.Transparent,color.Transparent)
  else if (theBrushStyle = HatchStyle.ZigZag) then
     thebrush2 := new SolidBrush(FillColor)
  else
     theBrush1 := new HatchBrush(theBrushStyle,FillColor,color.Transparent);

  if (thePen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Custom) then
    thepen.Color := Color.Transparent;

  pts := new point[pcount];

  if pcount >= 2 then
  begin
    if Active then
    begin
      for i := 0 to pcount-1 do
        pts[i] := point(points[i]);
      Translate(var pts,pcount);

      thepen.Color := EdgeColor(thepen.Color);
      fillColor := self.BackColor(FillColor);
      if visible then
      begin
        if filled then
        begin
            if theBrushStyle = HatchStyle.ZigZag then
                g.FillPolygon(theBrush2,pts)
            else 
                g.FillPolygon(thebrush1,pts);

            g.DrawPolygon(thepen, pts);
        end
        else
            g.DrawLines(thePen, pts);
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      for i := 0 to pcount-1 do
        pts[i] := point(points[i]);

      if filled then
      begin
            if theBrushStyle = HatchStyle.ZigZag then
                g.FillPolygon(theBrush2,pts)
            else 
                g.FillPolygon(thebrush1,pts);

            g.DrawPolygon(thepen,pts);        
      end
      else
        g.DrawLines(new Pen(color.Black),pts);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Any help or hints or clues will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the error is about invalid parameters, you should actually post the code with the variable declarations and initialization of the *parameters**. Vague descriptions about them are not useful.

Comment: Where are `points` and `pcount` coming from as they're not declared anywhere in the code you posted. (If you want help here, you need to give us the information to use to help you. Vague descriptions and code that depends on outside variables you don't provide aren't useful at all.)

Comment: @KenWhite, Those variables are defined in its class. `points` is an arraylist of points, pcount is number of points in the arraylist.

Comment: OK. So we have an unknown set of values in an arraylist (that you don't provide) being placed into a local array, which is then sent to a method called `Translate` (that you also don't provide) as a `var` parameter (meaning that `Translate` can modify them), and we're supposed to guess what might be wrong somewhere along the line with those unknown values that are changed in some unknown way. Does that properly summarize the question you're asking?

Comment: @KenWhite, Mouse location is added to the `points` arraylist as one is clicking on the winform with a mouse. So, if you clicked and dragged the mouse and released it, two points will be stored into `points` arraylist. `points` is dynamic. If you want, I can post the mouse event code. :)

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for your comments. Because of your comments, I actually start to think outside of the box and poked around the mouse events and that's where the problem was. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your pts array has less than 2 points, it will throw the parameter is not valid error.

Make sure your array has more then enough points to draw the lines.

Comment: at LarsTech, You are right. That's why I have a check `if (pcount>=2) then` block. I know you have to have at least 2 or more points for it to draw.

Comment: @digitalanalog It's the only way I could duplicate the error.  Where are points[] coming from and check what you are doing in the Translate() function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got this error, because somehow draw method always fired first even though the program was in the middle of adding point to the arraylist `points`. That meant arraylist was less than 2 points. Thus, the error. :)